# Using WebP fallback with CSP

Tags: html, content-security-policy, hugo

I'm using the following to use WebP images with a JPG fallback:

```
<img 
    src="{{ $img_webp_desktop.RelPermalink }}" 
    onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='{{ $img_jpg_desktop.RelPermalink }}';" 
    loading="lazy"
    height="{{ $img_jpg_desktop.Height }}" 
    width="{{ $img_jpg_desktop.Width }}">
```

However, with my CSP set to `script-src 'self'`, the `onerror` inline script doesn't get executed and the fallback doesn't work.

Is there any way to make this work with the CSP? Worst case scenario, I can enable `unsafe-hashes`.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data-...` attribute like that:

```
<img 
    src="{{ $img_webp_desktop.RelPermalink }}" 
    data-src="{{ $img_jpg_desktop.RelPermalink }}" 
    loading="lazy"
    height="{{ $img_jpg_desktop.Height }}" 
    width="{{ $img_jpg_desktop.Width }}">
```

and then universally add `onerror` event listeners to all images having data-src attr:

```
imgList = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");
imgList.forEach( function(img) {
  img.addEventListener( 'error', function(e) {
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    e.target.src = e.target.getAttribute("data-src");
    });
  });
```

> Worst case scenario, I can enable `'unsafe-hashes'`.

Yes, it's really worst. Safari does not support `'unsafe-hashes'`. It's hard to manage a lot of `'hash-values'`, all `onerror` will have an unique one. And after change image name you'll need to recalc and replace hash.